# How to find the contract address

Tags: contracts

I'm trying to add BTC to my Metamask wallet. I need the contract address of BTC for that. Where can I find it? They are always at Coinmarketcap, but not for BTC.

Answer (score 1):

BTC does not have a 'contract address', it is the native token of the Bitcoin network.

As mentioned by Romo, a Metamask wallet cannot hold BTC. You will need a proper bitcoin wallet for that.

Answer (score -1):

Metamask is an ERC-20 wallet, It's only support for ERC-20 token.
[You can check ERC-20 token list here](https://etherscan.io/tokens)

So, for Bitcoin, you would not be able to send it or store it in the MetaMask wallet.
however, You can use 'Wrapped BTC (WBTC)' instead because it is equal to btc.

Comment: WBTC is not 'equal' to BTC, it is a separate token issued by a third party that has wildly different trust and security assumptions.